# glReadPixels incorrect when x or y are not 0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to read the RGBA value of a pixel with `glReadPixels`. My problem is that whenever I try to read a pixel I get weird values. I have written the following debug code:

```
ByteBuffer pb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(400);
pb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
pb.position(0);
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, 10, 10, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pb);
byte b [] = new byte[400];
pb.get(b); //Here I get [0, 0, 31, -1, 0, 0, 31, 1....] which is the correct value

ByteBuffer pt = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
pt.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
pt.position(0);
GLES20.glReadPixels(1, 0, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pt);
b= new byte[4];
pt.get(b); //Here I get [-84, 100, -44, -81]
```

This misalignment when reading pixels only happens when I `eglChooseConfig`a RGB_565 config as opposed to a RGB_888 config, so I assume that has something to do with it, but I expect that there is something that I can do to read the correct pixel besides reading the whole picture and looking in the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

You say this is only happening when you change the `eglChooseConfig` to RGB_565 rather than `ARGB_888`.

However, when you call `glReadPixels`, you're passing `GLES20.GL_RGBA`. Try instead to pass `GLES20.GL_RGB565` to match the configuration you chose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I don't really understand that parameter, but what I gather from https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml is that it is used to specify the return format of the read pixels, not the format of the stored pixels. Is that correct?